# Meeting reminders disappearing after accepting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a particular user whose Outlook is acting up. Whenever he accepts a meeting invitation from a specific person, the reminders get turned off in the calendar. Every other person who got the meeting invitation still gets the reminders.

This is the only thread that I found somewhat relevant:  http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/32118199/lost-functionality-when-accepting-meeting-requests.aspx

This is weird though because he doesn't have any rules that should cause the meeting invitations to be stored in a weird folder or anything, they are left alone. I tried loading his profile and accepting the invitation on my end, and it went through fine (it was marked down in the calendar with a 15 minute reminder). When I looked at previous meetings he accepted from that person, there is indeed no reminder set.

Any suggestions?

Windows XPSP3, Outlook 2007, Exchange 2k3

Comment: There are a bunch of Outlook options controlling the calendar, meeting invitations and reminders.  Have you looked through those to see if he has anything set differently?

Comment: You imply but don't state this doesn't happen with invitations FROM other users.  Have you tested this?  My guess is it's the default settings on this user's calendar that they do not set a reminder.

Comment: Also, has the reminder box popped up at all? Sometimes if he has old reminders (and a lot of them.) Outlook cannot handle any new ones.

Comment: //// boot14 - nothing has been messed with on a deep level, but could you tell me what settings could possibly cause this so I can look at them? //// JNK - The user's reminders work as expected if he accepts a meeting from anyone other than that specific person. //// Cole - The user is able to accept other invitations and the reminder works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**On invite disappearing when responding :**

*Updated for Outlook 2010:*
Go to "File > Options", and select "Mail" from the vertical menu on the left. Scroll down to the "Send Messages" heading, and *uncheck* "Delete meeting requests and notifications from Inbox after responding."

*For older versions of Outlook:*
Go to = outlook > tools > options. 
On the = preference tab click the email options button and then on the window that opens click the advance email options button. on the bottom section of the window find the tickbox for: ---Delete email email request from inbox when responding.  This should be NOT ticked if you want to keep the invite in the inbox. else it will delete the invite once you respond.

**Now on the reminders:**

If you dont have a reminder time for your calendar then it will take what comes with the invite. the invite gets send out with your setting for this. 
for example. mine is setup to remind me of events 10 mins before it starts. When I accept an invite it defaults to 10 mins. If I did not have that setup and supposed you send the invite to me and your reminders are set for 15 mins, then when I accept it will take 15 mins for my reminder in my calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the users profile on thier local machine?

Since everything is working for others users, and thier account at a different location, it's presumably something wrong with on thier machine. Resetting the profile might remove the issue entirely.

So, try [creating another profile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918/en-us) for this user on thier machine (feel free to not remove the old one just yet!) and see if that works correctly.

If it does either get the user to reconfigure the new profile and user than from now on, or you've at least narrowed the problem down a bit.